# Monotouch: UIAlertView and WCF services, debugger.StackTrace

Tags: wcf, xamarin.ios, uialertview

I'm currently using WCF in monotouch to call an existing service and a custom UIAlertView.

The problem is that if I create an UIAlertView as class instance and the I do the following:

```
public override void ViewDidAppear()
{
 _alertView.Message = "Loading...";
 _alertView.Show();

 _client.GetDataAsync("test");
 _client.GetDataCompleted += GetDataCompletedDelegate;

 base.ViewDidAppear();
}

void GetDataCompletedDelegate(object sender, GetDataEventArgs)
{
 // do someting with data
 _alertView.Hide();
}
```

it works but this advice is written in console : **UIAlertView: wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003**

else, if I try to run this code:

```
public override void ViewDidAppear()
{
 using(CustomAV _alertView = new CustomAV())
 {
   _alertView.Message = "Loading...";
   _alertView.Show();

   _client.GetDataAsync("test");
   _client.GetDataCompleted += delegate{ 
     InvokeOnMainThread(delegate{
      // do someting with data
      _alertView.Hide();
     });
  };
 }

 base.ViewDidAppear();
}
```

the first time the code run, but now alert is shown. The second time the simulator can't startup. **Couldn't register "com.yourcompany.wcftest" with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code. This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.StackTrace.** In this case I have to reboot the machine.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

Thank you Geoff, I've checked my code and into GetDataCompletedDelegate I've inserted a function that runs inside the UI Thread.

```
InvokeOnMainThread(delegate{
 doSomething();
});

private void doSomething()
{
 // do stuff here
 _alertView.Hide();
}
```

The fency error continues to appear. If I use your solution inside doSomething() method, it works

```
_alertView.InvokeOnMainThread(delegate{
 _alertView.Hide();
});
```

Why? Maybe I didn't understand, but in the first snippet of code do something() works in the UI thread!! Isn't true?

Comment: It always good practice to run *all* changes to the UI on the main thread. So put your `_alertView.Show()` inside a `InvokeOnMainThread(delegate{})`. This can sometimes cause unusual behaviour. It may not solve your problem but like I said, it can be the cause of some unusual behaviour.

Comment: Thank you Luke. The fact is that `_alertView.Show()` (in the second section of code) is running in the main thread, insn't true?

Comment: the `_alertView.Hide()` is but I can't see that the `.Show()` is...unless your custom class runs it on the main thread itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 seperate problems here.

1: _alertView.Hide () is not running on the UI thread (this is what causes the fences error)

2: In your second example you're disposing the UIAlertVeiw immediately after creating it, but you have a instance delegate dangled off it.  This crashes the runtime in a hard way, and then when you run it again since the old crashed process is still running the simulator wont let you start a second instance.

Use case #1 but do _alterView.InvokeOnMainThread (delegate { _alertView.Hide (); });